# Pandas merging/updating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `pandas` dataframes such like:

```
   un  do
76  0   1
32  2   3
12  0   2
56  0   1
78  2   3
6   4   4
```

and

```
    un  do
76  0   5
32  2   3
12  1   2
56  0   1
78  2   3
6   4   4
34  3   3
78  h   3
23  2   -34
```

So they represent something like previous and actual data. And I need to join all the different rows.
I am about to kill myself, but I can't join them by `pandas` means.

I want to get such dataframe:

```
    un  do  chan
76  0   5   changed
76  0   1   None
32  2   3   None
12  1   2   changed
12  0   2   None
56  0   1   None
78  2   3   None
6   4   4   None
34  3   3   None
78  h   3   None
23  2   -34 None
```

Comment: just use a for loop comparing df1['un'] with df2['un'] and df1['do'] df2['do']
Append to a new list called chan either changed or None depending on your logic.

Afterwards create a new dataframe with un do and chan as columns and append chan to your data.

Comment: Using loops in dataframes is generally not a good idea

Comment: Does the data need to be in that order for the output or are you okay with any order, as long as the index is preserved?

Comment: Yes, any order is ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate your 2 dataframes and then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to update duplicate rows by index.

```
# concatenate, reset index to elevate index to series, drop duplicates
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index().drop_duplicates()

# add change series dependent on duplicates by index
df['change'] = np.where(df.duplicated('index'), 'changed', None)

# reset index for desired output
df = df.set_index('index')

print(df)

       un  do   change
index                 
76      0   1     None
32      2   3     None
12      0   2     None
56      0   1     None
78      2   3     None
6       4   4     None
76      0   5  changed
12      1   2  changed
34      3   3     None
78      0   3  changed
23      2 -34     None
```

Note I've changed your `un` value for `78` in `df2` to ensure you have numeric data, I'm assuming this is a typo. Otherwise, I suggest you choose a non-used numeric number to make sure you don't revert to `object` dtype.

Comment: Thank you sooo much